# Load and convert a lot of images to array of size (n,224,224,3) from path

Tags: python, list, numpy, keras

I'm currently loading images, creating an array out of it and appending it to a list. Sadly this seems to eat up all of my RAM for the amount of images I'm trying to load (20k).

Code:

```
def convert_image_to_array(files,relpath):
    images_as_array=[]
    len_files = len(files)
    i = 0
    print("---ConvImg2Arr---")
    print("---STARTING---")
    for file in files:
        images_as_array.append(img_to_array(load_img(relpath+file, target_size=(soll_img_shape, soll_img_shape)))/255)
        if i == int(len_files*0.2):
            print("20% done")
        if i == int(len_files*0.5):
            print("50% done")
        if i == int(len_files*0.8):
            print("80% done")

        i +=1
    print("---DONE---")
    return images_as_array
```

calling it with X_train being coming from train_test_split:

```
x_train =  convert_image_to_array_opt(X_train,rel_path)
```

What is an more efficient way to load all those images?

Edit:

Using .flow_from_directory() from Keras solved my issues but I would still like to know how it could be done the way I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the method `load_img` is not the bottleneck, `convert_image_to_array_opt` loads all the images (20k) into memory. However, `flow_from_directory` methods only loads one bath of images at a time (typical batch sizes are 32, 64, ... 1024)

A possible way to redesign `convert_image_to_array_opt` will be to take the batch size as argument and load and `yield` a numpy array loaded with `bath_size` images only (along with labels). And while training enumerate on `convert_image_to_array_opt` method which return batch_size X's and y's which you can train on.

Comment: load_img is actually from keras.preprocessing.image !

Comment: So the assumption that `load_img` is not a bottleneck is true then. Rest of my answer is the way I normally approach when I write my own data loaders.